# What's the trailing symbols within an char array which initialized with brace-enclosed lists in clang?

Tags: arrays, c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  char name1[] = {'f','o','o'};
  char name2[] = "foo";
  printf("%s\n", name1);
  printf("%s\n", name2);
  return 0;
}
```

running the code above results in :

```
foox\363\277\357\376
foo
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

So, what's the difference between these 2 initializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first array (*i.e.,* `{'f','o','o'}`) will not have the `null` character `'\0'`, wheres the second (*i.e.,* `"foo"`) will.

The [printf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) specification when using the `%s` *says* the following:

> If no l modifier is present: The const char * argument is expected to
> be a pointer to an array of character type (pointer to a string).
> **Characters from the array are written up to (but not including) a
> terminating null byte ('\0'); if a precision is specified, no more
> than the number specified are written.** If a precision is given, no
> null byte need be present; if the precision is not specified, or is
> greater than the size of the array, the array must contain a
> terminating null byte.

Since, your `printf` did not include the precision, it will write up characters  from the array until reaching the null byte (`'\0'`). Consequently, in the case of the `char name1[] = {'f','o','o'};` resulting in the printf write up characters out of the memory that was allocated for the *name1* array. Such behaviour is considered to be *undefined*.

This is the reason why `printf("%s\n", name1);` prints *foo* plus some extra symbols from the next positions in memory that *should not have been accessed*, whereas with `printf("%s\n", name2);` it prints exactly the *string* "`foo"` as it is.

Answer (score 2):

`name1` is an array of three characters `{'f', 'o', 'o'}`.

`name2` is an array of **four** characters `{'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'}`.

`printf("%s", ...)` expects an array terminated with a null character. Because `name1` isn't, you start dereferencing characters past the end of the array which can have the traditional undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There are no trailing symbols in the array.

But `printf`’s `%s` format expects a *string*, and the array `name1` isn’t a string: by definition, C strings are zero terminated … and your array isn’t. So the behaviour is undefined, and what seems to happen in your particular case is that `printf` continues printing random values that happen to be in memory just behind the contents of `name1`.

Answer (score 0):

In C language if you are initializing string with character by character initializer you need to put `'\0'` which is NULL/terminating character to indicate the end of string.
so name1 should be `{'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'}`

`x\363\277\357\376` that you can see at the end of your output is just garbage value which is printed just because printf could not find '\0' at the end of your string name1.

For name2 you used double quote to initialize the string which automatically puts a `'\0'` at the end of string.